# With EditorJS, saving block, and restoring: always one empty block at the top of area;

Tags: editorjs

- I input text in editorjs area, and save it when it changes. For exemple, I input one word, and get one block.
- To restore it later, I first clear blocks, and then add each block:

  myEditor.blocks.clear();
  for (let block of notes.blocks) {
  myEditor.blocks.insert(block.type, block.data);
  }

And each time there is an empty line at the beginning of editor area. Why ?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this `defaultBlock: "embed",` to the configuration of EditorJS